# Как изменить папку для временных файлов 1с сервера взаимодействия на linux

Tags: linux, 1с

Имеется запущенный 1с сервер взаимодействие на линукс. Столкнулись с проблемой при загрузке информационной базы из .dt (файловый формат хранения) в postgreSQL:

"Ошибка загрузки информационной базы. В информационную базу загружены не все данные
по причине:
На устройстве нет свободного места '/tmp/v8_1xeSwD_a.tmp'. 28(0x0000001C): No space left on device"

По нашим предположениям - это связанно с небольшим количеством места на системном диске (чуть меньше 4Гб). Хочется изменить место хранения и взаимодействия с временными файлами на другой диск, но как это сделать?

В /home/usr1cv8/.bashrc и /home/usr1cv8/.profile добавлена переменная TMPDIR с нужным каталогом для хранения. И команда env отображает эту переменную с корректным значением, но всё равно при рестарте службы, временные файлы пишутся в /tmp папку

Comment: Увеличить свап пробовал?

Comment: Свап на максимуме

Comment: На максимуме? Ты же в курсе, что "максимум" - это всё оставшееся свободное место на винте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выключи tmpfs

```
systemctl disable tmp.mount
```

Или удали строчку в fstab.

Добавление свапа и увеличение tmpfs в случае с одинес не поможет.

Если и в этом случае не хватит, то самое надежное монтирование другого каталога поверх темпа в корне.

```
mount -o bind /data/tmp /tmp
```

(можно добавить в fstab)

По переменной - её надо прописать /etc/init.d/srv1cv83 стартовом скрипте. В моей установке это bash скрипт и переменная добавляется через перед `#invoke function main`

```
export TMPDIR=/data/tmp/
```

Но я не видел такой переменной в документации к серверу.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04: `Failed to stop tmp.mount: Unit tmp.mount not loaded.`.

Comment: Кстати да, были попытки добавления переменной в /etc/init.d/srv1cv83

Но просто тупое объявление переменной по аналогии с уже имеющимися там, не сработало. Вот как добавлял:

Environment=TMPDIR=/media/vault.holding/1c/H1/tmp-1c-data
Environment=TEMPDIR=/media/vault.holding/1c/H1/tmp-1c-data

Comment: Как я понимаю, в этом же файле (/etc/init.d/srv1cv8), идет запуск самого 1с сервера через:

ExecStart=/opt/1cv8/x86_64/8.3.21.1484/ragent -d ${SRV1CV8_DATA} -port ${SRV1CV8_PORT} ...

Но как бы я не хотел, не получилось найти какой параметр нужно прописать, чтобы изменить месторасположения каталога временных файлов

Comment: У меня не ExecStart... Там большой баш скрипт. Может у вас новая платформа? Какая версия?

Comment: Спасибо огромное @eri.

Помогла команда: mount -o bind /data/tmp /tmp

Answer (score 2):

Получилось изменить путь для хранения временных файлов путем указания переменной среды TMPDIR в файле, который в моем случае назывался "/etc/systemd/system/srv1cv8-8.3.21.1674@.service" (Операционная система Debian11, версия сервера 1С 8.3.21.1674) в блоке [Service] прописал строчку Environment=TMPDIR=Путь

[image: Пример настройки]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1):

всегда хороший вариант обратиться к официальной документации.

https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/1736/hdoc гласит, что можно указать отдельный каталог для временных файлов для пользователя, под которым выполняется 1С.

достаточно в `.bash_profile` внести:

```
export TMPDIR=/path/to/drive/for/temp
```

и 1с будет писать все туда, а системный каталог для временных файлов останется на месте

Comment: ПО поводу:"всегда хороший вариант обратиться к официальной документации".
Обратился, сделал всё, как у 1с написано. Не заработало. Обратился в службу поддержки. Получил ответ, "У вас проявление ошибки 60001911, она сейчас на рассмотрении у разработчика". Обращению, на момент моего обращения, было уже пол года.

Comment: @Борис, но вы же сами и написали (в уже удалённом «ответе»), что вам именно этот совет и помог: указать путь к каталогу в переменной окружения `TMPDIR`.